# How to delay this evaluation

Tags: evaluation, mathematical-optimization, hold

I am trying to create two sets, then merge them (they have one common element) and then take the total of the new set.

Let's call them `set1` and `set2` while their union is called `set`

```
set1[t_,gh_,ga_]:=If[gh==0,Reap[For[i=0,i<=10,i++,Sow[fn[0,i,t,gh,ga]]]][[2,1]],{}];
set2[t_,gh_,ga_]:=If[ga==0,Reap[For[i=0,i<=10,i++,Sow[fn[i,0,t,gh,ga]]]][[2,1]],{}];
```

and

```
set[t_, gh_, ga_] := 
  Union[set1[t, gh, ga], set2[t, gh, ga]];
```

I call them by setting `t=gh=ga=0` and I get this:

```
set1[0,0,0]
```

> {fn[0,0,0,0,0],fn[0,1,0,0,0],fn[0,2,0,0,0],fn[0,3,0,0,0],fn[0,4,0,0,0],fn[0,5,0,0,0],fn[0,6,0,0,0],fn[0,7,0,0,0],fn[0,8,0,0,0],fn[0,9,0,0,0],fn[0,10,0,0,0]}

```
set2[0,0,0]
```

> {fn[0,0,0,0,0],fn[1,0,0,0,0],fn[2,0,0,0,0],fn[3,0,0,0,0],fn[4,0,0,0,0],fn[5,0,0,0,0],fn[6,0,0,0,0],fn[7,0,0,0,0],fn[8,0,0,0,0],fn[9,0,0,0,0],fn[10,0,0,0,0]}

and finally

```
set[0,0,0]
```

> {fn[0,0,0,0,0],fn[0,1,0,0,0],fn[0,2,0,0,0],fn[0,3,0,0,0],fn[0,4,0,0,0],fn[0,5,0,0,0],fn[0,6,0,0,0],fn[0,7,0,0,0],fn[0,8,0,0,0],fn[0,9,0,0,0],fn[0,10,0,0,0],fn[1,0,0,0,0],fn[2,0,0,0,0],fn[3,0,0,0,0],fn[4,0,0,0,0],fn[5,0,0,0,0],fn[6,0,0,0,0],fn[7,0,0,0,0],fn[8,0,0,0,0],fn[9,0,0,0,0],fn[10,0,0,0,0]}

and then i simply ask for `set[0,0,0]//Total`.

Here is the thing. When I feed my program with some initial values everything works fine, unless the initial values are such that 
`fn[1,0,0,0,0]` is equal to `fn[0,1,0,0,0]` and so on, for example suppose that they are both equao to `0.2`

since two sets (set1,set2) are equal after evaluation 
for example:

```
set1 = {0.20, 0.30, 0.40}
set2 = {0.20, 0.30, 0.40}
```

when I ask for their union I get `set = {0.20, 0.30, 0.40}` and later on I get half the total I was supposed to get: `set[0,0,0]//Total = 0.90` while I was expecting `1.80`

So basically I need to form `set` before fn is evaluated. It is crucial to define fn though before those sets. 
I tried hold, Unevaluated, Cell [Evaluatable->False] and other functions/properties but none workded. Any idea?

Comment: What about starting the iterator `i` of `set2` at `1` rather than `0`, and then using `Join` instead of `Union`?

Comment: You may be interested in defining `set1` as follows: `set1[t_, 0, ga_] := fn[0, #, t, 0, ga] & /@ Range[0, 10]; set1[t_, gh_, ga_] := {};` (and similarly for `set2`).

Comment: @xavier thanks for replying. Your first suggestion is my initial approach for a workaround, if nothing more elegant could come in mind. Your second is really clever, though I need to define set1,set2 in a way where gh,ga get actual values in a future stage. What I implemented is `set1[t_,gh_,ga_]:=If[gh==0,Reap[For[i=0,i<=10,i++,Sow[fn[0,i,t,gh,ga]]]][[2,1]],{}];
set2[t_,gh_,ga_]:=If[ga==0,Reap[For[i=0,i<=10,i++,Sow[fn[i,0,t,gh,ga]]]][[2,1]],{}];
NoGoalSet[t_,gh_,ga_]:=Delete[Join[NoGoalHomeSet[t,gh,ga],NoGoalAwaySet[t,gh,ga]],1];
`

Comment: @xavier  (cont) in order to delete the only duplicate value (fn[0, 
   0, , , ,]) before evaluating
and `Deleteduplicates` worked the very same way as `Union`, so I just \
used `Delete` by deleting the 1 st element of my list (0, 
  0) which is basically what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you already defined the function called `fn` while you are executing your code a simple solution is to execute it inside a `Block` redefining `fn` locally:

```
fn[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] := a + b + c + d + e;

Block[{fn},
 Union[set1[1, 0, 0], set2[1, 0, 0]] // Total
 ]
(* Out[1] = 131 *)

Union[set1[1, 0, 0], set2[1, 0, 0]] // Total
(* Out[2] = 66 *)
```

where I arbitrarily defined a `fn` function to show that this works

Comment: it just works, thanks. I was not aware of `Block` function usage. Good to be taught something new. It is my understanding that it actually gives prioritization in creating the set (defined by `Union`) and then evaluates it using `fn` to get `Total`, correct?

Comment: @TomZinger it simply redefined locally `fn`. In this case undefining it locally. This means that `set1` and `set2` evaluate as you shown in your original post, without `fn` evaluating to actual numbers, and you can count the number of different `fn[...]` objects. I do agree with xavier that using `Join` would make more sense for this kind of counting anyway, and directly avoids the problem that I solved with `Block`